# boost::assign with std::map

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, stl

I tried to  use `boost::assign` with `std::map` by using `operator+=()` but I couldn't make it work.

Below my code

```
#include <boost/assign/std/map.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_inserter.hpp>

using namespace boost::assign;

typedef map<string,char> Data;
Data dt;
dt += ("CIAO", 'C'),("SALUT",'S');
```

I have the following error

```
/usr/local/include/boost/assign/list_inserter.hpp|113| error: 
no matching function for call to ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char, 
std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, 
std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >, char> > >::insert(char&)’
```

Am I missing something here? Do I have to define a `std::less` for this container to make it work?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#intro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're conflating two features of `boost.assign`.

It does support `+=`, but with comma-separated *values*, and map *values* are in fact pairs of key→mapped.

So, you'd have to write:

```
dt += (make_pair("CIAO", 'C')), (make_pair("SALUT",'S'));
```

This is predominantly why the `insert` syntax is also provided, so that you can write:

```
insert (dt) ("CIAO", 'C'), ("SALUT", 'S');
```

The [documentation for this stuff](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#intro) is pretty good…

Comment: Obvious..I didn't think about it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use boost::assign very often but the only Way I am aware of is to add `std::pair` to your map.
So changing your code to:

```
dt += (pair<string,char>("CIAO", 'C')),(pair<string,char>("SALUT",'S'));
```

should do the trick.